# Node js and MySQL, i need to implement dynamic MySql connections, depending of who is connected to the server

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I got an app, and i got different customers, let's say:
customer_1,
customer_2

i got the sequlize config

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const db = {};
let sequelize = new Sequelize('db_schema', 'user', 'password', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306',
    dialectOptions: {
        supportBigNumbers: true,
        bigNumberStrings: true
    },
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    logging: console.log
});

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".")!==0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        let model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Every customer is going to have its own db_schema, so i need to connect every customer with its schema,

How to accomplish that?

Im trying to look up in internet but i couldnt find a solution.

Comment: I imagine that you could have a table or however you prefer to do it, where it is defined that each user corresponds to a db_schema. And have code in your backend that creates or defines which schema is being used, depending on the user in question.

Comment: thats the problem, i have no idea how to do it. this is my first time trying to accomplish this kind of scenarios, but i want to use the same server, because the only thing that change is the db_schema connection.

Comment: I'd rethink your approach. Even with huge multi-tenant systems I've worked on, they were still on the same DB

Comment: Can you explain where you get stuck?

Comment: ok, and how do you do if a client want his data, or when the db has a lot of data, and a new client make a query, the server have to search in the whole db, instead of a new empty schema? @Phil

Comment: how to implement this approach. @Evert

Comment: That's correct. I don't see what the problem is though

Comment: @luismiguelcastromartinez. Can you write an if statement that connects to a database depending on the current customer. If no, why not? Elaborate on where you are stuck.

Comment: If we taking about Sequelize and using the same tables and models in different schemas of the same DB then you will need as many Sequelize instances as many customers you will connect (at first connection attempt just to save memory and connections) OR just register model definitions in the single Sequelize instance with different names maybe prefixed/suffixed with customer id or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of pool of databases in a singleton pattern with identifiers as for example in this example code:

```js
class DynamicDB  {
  constructor(database) {
    // all config, models, etc...
    this.instance = {};

  }

  // generates unique identifier for your instance
  static getDatabaseUniqueIdentifier(database) {
    return JSON.stringify(database).toString('base64');
  }

  /**
   * get instance of the database
   * @returns {DynamicDB}
   * @throws {Error} if instance is not initialized
   */
  static getInstance(database = {}) {
    !this.instance && (this.instance = {});
    const _id = DynamicDB.getDatabaseUniqueIdentifier(database);
    if (!this.instance[_id]) {
      this.instance[_id] = new DynamicDB(database || {});
    }
    return this.instance[_id];
  }

  /**
   * Close database connection and delete instance from memory
   * Use only if necessary
   * @returns {void}
   * @throws {Error} if instance is not initialized
   */
  static closeDatabase(database) {
    const _id = DynamicDB.getDatabaseUniqueIdentifier(database);
    this.instance[_id] && this.instance[_id].connection.close();
    this.instance[_id] = null;
  }

}

module.exports = DynamicDB;
```